How to extract the values from Order, and Customers. What XSLT stylesheet to use to get to the output?

<Orders>
<Order>
    <CustomerID>VK</CustomerID>
    <Customer>
        <CompanyName>Vins et alcools Chevalier</CompanyName>
        <Country>France</Country>
        <CustomerID>VINET</CustomerID>
        <City>Reims</City>
        <ContactName>Paul Henriot</ContactName>
        <ContactTitle>Accounting Manager</ContactTitle>
    </Customer>
    <ShipCountry>France</ShipCountry>
    <OrderID>10248</OrderID>
    <EmployeeID>5</EmployeeID>
    <OrderDate>1996-07-04T00:00:00.000</OrderDate>
</Order>
</Orders>

The input I am providing is above and need the below output. what changes should i make to the XSLT code to get ot the output. like the value of select statements
Output
<Orders>
    <Order>
        <CustomerID>VINET</CustomerID>
        <CompanyName>Vins et alcools Chevalier</CompanyName>
        <Country>France</Country>
        <CustomerID>VINET</CustomerID>
        <City>Reims</City>
        <ContactName>Paul Henriot</ContactName>
        <ContactTitle>Accounting Manager</ContactTitle>
        <ShipCountry>France</ShipCountry>
        <OrderID>10248</OrderID>
        <EmployeeID>5</EmployeeID>
        <OrderDate>1996-07-04T00:00:00.000</OrderDate>
    </Order>
</Orders>

My current XSLT style sheet is incorrect and it is added below. Needing the correct stylesheet code. to get the above output. Pls check the below stylesheet and see what changes need to be made.
How to correctly use the value of select statement for the result
xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h2>All Orders</h2>
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#003333">
    <xsl:comment>green</xsl:comment>
    <th>CUSTOMERID</th>
    <th>SHIPCOUNTRY</th>
    <th>ORDERID</th>
    <th>EMPLOYEEID</th>
    <th>COMPANYNAME</th>
    <th>COUNTRY</th>
    <th>SHIPCOUNTRY</th>
    <th>CITY</th>
    <th>CONTACTTITLE</th>
    <th>ORDERDATE</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="Orders/Order">
<xsl:sort select="OrderID"/>
<tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="CustomerID"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="ShipCountry"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="OrderID"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="EmployeeID"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="CompanyName"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="Country"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="ShipCountry"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="City"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="ContactTitle"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="OrderDate"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>


While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) Well-formed input XML with all relevant namespaces.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Your desired output is not clear. Is it XML or HTML?

"what changes should i make to the XSLT code" None. Throw it away, spend an hour with an XSLT book or tutorial and write your own. This is a trivial task, an hour may be even too much.

Hi Michael. Thank you so for your time for finding a solution.I tried this  approach and got the result.  <xsl:value-of select="Orders_Qry/ShipVia"/>,       <xsl:value-of select="Customer/CompanyName"/>
Thanks

Please try the following XSLT that is using a so called Identity Transform pattern.
Input XML
<Orders>
    <Order>
        <CustomerID>VK</CustomerID>
        <Customer>
            <CompanyName>Vins et alcools Chevalier</CompanyName>
            <Country>France</Country>
            <CustomerID>VINET</CustomerID>
            <City>Reims</City>
            <ContactName>Paul Henriot</ContactName>
            <ContactTitle>Accounting Manager</ContactTitle>
        </Customer>
        <ShipCountry>France</ShipCountry>
        <OrderID>10248</OrderID>
        <EmployeeID>5</EmployeeID>
        <OrderDate>1996-07-04T00:00:00.000</OrderDate>
    </Order>
</Orders>

XSLT
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"
               omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <!--Identity Transform pattern-->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Customer">
         <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Output XML
<Orders>
  <Order>
    <CustomerID>VK</CustomerID>
    <CompanyName>Vins et alcools Chevalier</CompanyName>
    <Country>France</Country>
    <CustomerID>VINET</CustomerID>
    <City>Reims</City>
    <ContactName>Paul Henriot</ContactName>
    <ContactTitle>Accounting Manager</ContactTitle>
    <ShipCountry>France</ShipCountry>
    <OrderID>10248</OrderID>
    <EmployeeID>5</EmployeeID>
    <OrderDate>1996-07-04T00:00:00.000</OrderDate>
  </Order>
</Orders>


Hi Yitzhak, thank you so much for your help. I got the solution. Made some small changes seeng otherthreads from stack over flow. Like this .       <xsl:value-of select="Orders_Qry/ShipVia"/>

@Kas, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as Answer.

Please mark it as answered. You simply need to mark an answer as correct (the green check image).
Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted".
